# getting id of selected row in table laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, controller, primary-key, laravelcollective

So I'm trying CRUD using laravel collective, my problem is how to get the id of a selected row in order to edit it.

it looks like if i select a certain column i want to edit in my table, the id that it gets is the id of the last row instead of the selected row.

Here's my view.

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Course</th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($cruds as $crud)
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{$crud->id}}</th>
                            <td>{{$crud->firstName}}</td>
                            <td>{{$crud->lastName}}</td>
                            <td>{{$crud->course}}</td>
               
                            <td><button class= "btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"> Edit </button></td>
                            <td><button class= "btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"> Delete </button></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

here's my modal

```
{{-- <-- Edit Modal --> --}}
  <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">EDIT DATA</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body"> 
            
            {!! Form::open(['action' => ['CrudController@update', $crud->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('firstName','First Name')}}
                {{Form::text('firstName',$crud->firstName,['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('lastName','Last Name')}}
                {{Form::text('lastName',$crud->lastName,['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('course','Course')}}
                {{Form::text('course',$crud->course,['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
            {{Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
            </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here's my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstName' =>'required',
            'lastName' => 'required',
            'course' => 'required'
        ]); 

        //Adding Data
        $crud = Crud::find($id); 
        $crud->firstName = $request->input('firstName');
        $crud->lastName = $request->input('lastName');
        $crud->course = $request->input('course');
        $crud->save();

        return redirect('/crud');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
     <script>
       $(document).on('click', '.edit-modal', function() {
        $('#id').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#firstName').val($(this).data('firstName'));
        $('#lastName').val($(this).data('lastName'));
        $('#course').val($(this).data('course'));
        $('#ModalEditForm').modal('show');
     });
    </script>
```

and give each input an ID, and send the id of record as hidden input
remove the id from the route and the controller method and send the id as hidden input

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to do this:

In the list:

```
@foreach ($cruds as $crud)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $crud->id }}</th>
        <td>{{ $crud->firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ $crud->lastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ $crud->course }}</td>

        <td><button class= "btn btn-warning edit-modal" data-id="{{ $crud->id }}"> Edit </button></td>
        <td><button class= "btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"> Delete </button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

MODAL:

```
{{-- <-- Edit Modal --> --}}
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">EDIT DATA</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-modal', function() {
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    $.get('/your/api/getById/'+id, function(data){
        $('#editModal .modal-body').html(data);
    });
});
```

Inside of a modal window etc modal_edit.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['CrudController@update', $crud->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
  <div class="form-group">
      {{Form::label('firstName','First Name')}}
      {{Form::text('firstName',$crud->firstName,['class' => 'form-control'])}}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      {{Form::label('lastName','Last Name')}}
      {{Form::text('lastName',$crud->lastName,['class' => 'form-control'])}}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      {{Form::label('course','Course')}}
      {{Form::text('course',$crud->course,['class' => 'form-control'])}}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
  {{Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller:

```
public function getById(YourModel $crud){
    return view('modal_edit.blade.php', compact('crud'))->render();
}
```

If something is not clear, please contact. I will gladly help